# Then-current retail price

Tags: word-usage

What does the statement "the prorate portion is the then-current retail price of the item" mean? Does it mean the price I paid, or the current price, is being charged?

Comment: It means the price you paid then, i.e. at the time you bought the product.

Comment: thanks the retailer is trying to charge me the current price then pro rate it

Comment: @SConroy -  only if they paid full retail originally.  so if it was originally $80 on sale for $60 and now is retailing for $50.  The prorate portion would be $80 not the $60 they actually paid nor the $50 it’s currently retailing for.

Comment: Why are you being charged now if you already paid? It might help if you provided more context of how this phrases is being used.

Answer (score 0):

**then** as an adjective  [MacMillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/then)

> as an adjective (only before a noun):  at that time

As in:

> The then prime minister, Harold Wilson ...